# Rails joining multiple methods and scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

My rails app provides a list of services which are defined like this:

service.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :clients
has_many :translations, class_name: ServiceTranslation, dependent: :destroy

def with_translation(lang)
  includes(:translations)
      .where("service_translations.language_id=?", lang.id)
      .references(:service_translations)
end

scope :with_clients, -> { select("services.*, count(clients_services.service_id) as clients_count")
  .joins(:clients).group('services.id').order('clients_count desc') }
```

So the *with_translation* method is eager loading the translations for the service (name, content etc) and the scope *with_clients* is making sure that the services are ordered by the number of linked clients (also, if no client is linked to a service, the service is not showing)

Both methods are working when called separately in my services_controller:

services_controller.rb

```
class ServicesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    #@services = Service.with_clients.page(params[:page])
    #or
    @services = Service.with_translation(@lang).page(params[:page])
  end
end
```

All is good and dandy, but I need both of those methods working together, so when I do this:

```
@services = Service.with_clients.with_translation(@lang).page(params[:page])
```

I get this error message:

PG::Error: ERROR:  column "clients_count" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  DISTINCT "services"."id", clients_count AS alias_0 F...

I tried merging the two methods, creating the whole query in the controller, both in vain...any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure `with_translation` is an instance method?
Can you provide full log?
Also could you provide SQL logs when you invoke the scopes separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error suggest the output query have `clients_count` as a column but it is just an alias for `COUNT`.

Try running scopes in `rails console` and analysing the queries in the log one by one:

you say this works

```
Service.with_clients
```

first make sure two scopes combined without pagination work correctly

```
Service.with_clients.with_translation(@lang)
```

The resulting query should be like this:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT "services"."id", count(clients_services.service_id) AS clients_count FROM "services" 
INNER JOIN "clients_services" ON "clients_services"."service_id" = "services"."id" 
INNER JOIN "clients" ON "clients"."id" = "clients_services"."client_id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "service_translations" ON "service_translations"."service_id" = "services"."id" 
WHERE (service_translations.language_id=2) 
GROUP BY services.id
ORDER BY clients_count desc
```

Comment: Debugging in rails console helped me solve the issue. Thanks! :)
I needed to add 'service_translations.id' as a parameter in the group call and it worked.
The thing that caused the issue is Kaminari. Its method .page(params[:id]) messed up the query.

Comment: [Kaminari uses](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/blob/0c354253a352150d3f2b7f7527066a8a9f64ff6d/lib/kaminari/models/mongoid_extension.rb#L10) AR `limit` and `offset` methods.

Try adding them one by one to debug if further.